# Prevent component from rerendering when redux sibling state changes

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

ParentComponent renders ChildComponent that renders an array of objects that it gets from `state.foo`.  Inside each of these `state.foo` items is a button that fires an action that will update `state.bar`.

When I click this button, the entire `foo` collection re-renders even though I'm only calling an action to update the `bar` slice of the state tree. So, when clicking the button to update `bar`, the collection itself disappears and then reappears after the re-render.

**How do I prevent the `foo` slice of the state tree from rerendering so that I can leave it rendered while updating the `bar` slice of the state tree?**

```
class ParentComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <ChildComponent
      updateBarInStateTree={this.props.updateBarInStateTree}
      foo={this.props.foo} 
      bar={this.props.bar} 
    />
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    foo: state.foo,
    bar: state.bar,
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    updateBarInStateTree: () => dispatch(actionThatWillReturnNewBarInStateTree())
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ParentComponent);
```

```
class ChildComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.props.foo.map(f => (
          <div onClick={this.props.updateBarInStateTree}>Click me to update bar</div>
        ))
        }
      <div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Why pass in bar as props when it's not being used in ChildComponents? if you need it there then maybe consider using `shouldComponentUpdate` to check on specific props changes.

Comment: `bar` in the render will be a thing that shows up inside the `foo` items, so it does get used

Comment: if `bar` is used in the `ChildComponent`, wouldnt you want them to re-render when `bar` is updated?

Comment: I don't want `foo` to rerender, because when `foo` rerenders the entire collection disappears from the page and then comes back - kind of like a blink.  Rather, I just want to fire an action to update `bar` so that I can grab the value of `bar` as it comes back and render it in the right place, without touching `foo` at all.